# Firebase cloud functions sample addMessage Forbidden

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I'm starting with Firebase Cloud Functions. So, tried with example (https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started). I've successfully deployed functions, could see them in a list of functions.

But when I tries to run url, I receive such error:

`Error: Forbidden
Your client does not have permission to get URL /addMessage&text=test from this server.`

What could be the problem?

Comment: Looks like, first time I was able to execute this function, because I've found a record in real-time db.

Comment: https://appuals.com/fix-your-client-does-not-have-permission-to-get-url/ ???

Comment: Tried, nothing. Same problem for "new" browser.